# My Viber bot working very slow(Python) How can I make it faster

Tags: python, viber-bot, viber-bot-python

Here is part of my code, db.users_vi() is a list file. When the program comes to def viber_not, it starts working very slow, it send 1 message per 30 sec or even slower. How can I make it work faster, and why it's so slow?

```
def viber_not():

   users = db.users_vi()

   text = random.choice(texts)

   for k in users:
       try:
           viber.send_messages(k[1], [TextMessage(text=text)])
       except:
           pass
```

Comment: Have you tried multithreading?

Comment: No, I'm not. Can you please send me details about it? Where I can find information about  multithreading

Comment: API calls  on single-threaded applications will be very limited by the network latency since you are always waiting for the response. One way of solving this is making use of multithreading, in which you can send more submissions while waiting for the response of the others, here is a pretty good post about that https://creativedata.stream/multi-threading-api-requests-in-python/

Comment: Thank you, I'll try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to serialize data requested from DB. As most of them returns "cursor", not data. For some of them wrapping in `list` is enough, but look to documentation of that you use.

`users = list(db.users_vi())`